# Quantlib Python bootstrapping with ArithmeticOISRateHelper: cannot find a soluton for forward rate

Tags: programming, quantlib, bootstrapping, ois

I am trying to construct a curve based on OIS quotes. Fixed rates in those OIS are quoted againgst the arithmetic average of the floating rate. Consequently, I am using the correspoding helper class - ArithmeticOISRateHelper.

To my understanding, quantlib solver is unable to find a solution, while extracting a forward rate from the curve built with the set of ArithmeticOISRateHelpers.

The error message is

> RuntimeError: 1st iteration: failed at 1st alive instrument, pillar
> April 16th, 2024, maturity April 16th, 2024, reference date January
> 15th, 2024: root not bracketed: f[0.777738,1.28578] ->
> [-9.470000e-01,-9.470000e-01]

I have tried the procedure:
-with different rates;
-with and without discounting curve fed into helpers;
-with different interpolation methods: PiecewiseLogLinearDiscount, PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount  and so on.
Unfortunately, the calculation error persists regardless of the approach.

Below is the code with generic tenors and and two generic curves:
-zero_curve represents the risk free spot curve;
-swap_rates is the curve with OIS quotes.

My quetion with regrard to the code below:

1. Am I missing something critical?
2. Maybe, I am passing the data in the incorrect format for ArithmeticOISHelper?
3. I suspect the issue might also be in the forwardRate() itself, where I set the compouding to ql.Compounded. However, I am unaware of options except for ql.Compounded and ql.Simple.

```
import QuantLib as ql

# ql initial set up
today = ql.Date().todaysDate()
ql.Settings.instance().evalutationDate = today

business_conv = ql.ModifiedFollowing
day_count = ql.ActualActual(ql.ActualActual.ISDA)
calendar = ql.TARGET()
fixing_days = 1

on_index = ql.OvernightIndex(
    'on_index', fixing_days, ql.USDCurrency(), calendar, day_count)

# generic curves
tenors = ['3m', '6m', '9m', '1y']
days = [calendar.advance(today, ql.Period(tenor)) for tenor in tenors]
spot_rates = [0.05, 0.052, 0.0521, 0.0505]
swap_rates = [0.053, 0.054, 0.0546, 0.0524]

zero_curve = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(ql.ZeroCurve(days, spot_rates, day_count, calendar))
zero_curve.enableExtrapolation()

# building the swap curve object with helpers
helpers = []
for i in range(len(tenors)):
        arithm_helper = ql.ArithmeticOISRateHelper(
                        fixing_days, ql.Period(tenors[i]), ql.Monthly,
                        ql.QuoteHandle((ql.SimpleQuote(swap_rates[i]))),
                        on_index, ql.Monthly, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(0)),
                        0.03, 0, True, zero_curve)
        helpers.append(arithm_helper)

curve = ql.PiecewiseLogCubicDiscount(
         today, helpers, day_count)
curve.enableExtrapolation()

# extracting daily forwards
curve_dates = [ql.Date(serial) for serial in range(today.serialNumber(), days[-1].serialNumber()+1)]
fwd_rates = [curve.forwardRate(day, calendar.advance(day, 1, ql.Days), day_count, ql.Compounded).rate() for day in curve_dates]
```

Looking forward to your comments!

Best regards,
feesheep